# How do I get python to correctly read the numbers in variables for Arduino joystick

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

Im new to python and only started trying it yesterday. Im trying to build a controller with my Arduino and each joystick will tell python the direction it's moving. For now Im trying the get 1 joystick to tell python that it is facing right, but I'm having trouble with the final "if" statement in the code. This is for a lego ev3 to read via python

Here is my Arduino code

```
char userInput;
int data = 0;
int RIGHT = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if (Serial.available()> 0) {
  userInput = Serial.read();

if (analogRead(A0) / 4.01176470588 >=145) {
     RIGHT = 1;
  } else {
    RIGHT = 0;
  }

  if (userInput == 'g') {
      Serial.println(RIGHT);
}
}
}
```

and here is my python code

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem11201', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)

direction = 0

while 1:
    ser.write(b'g')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    direction = arduinoData 
    
    print(direction)
    
    if direction == '1' : 
        print("Joystick is turning right")
```

Nothing is outputted in the python terminal. I just want the "Joystick is turning right" to show and then I can move on with other directions and then the other joystick to eventually interface with the Lego EV3

Comment: note that I did remove the infinite print(direction) to prevent it from hiding the "Joystick is turning right"

Comment: Looks like you initially defined direction as an integer (direction = 0), but then you are trying to test it as a string.  Maybe you need direction = '0'

Answer (score -1):

In your Arduino code, you are sending an integer value but in your python code you are checking if the direction is a string version of 1.

Try this for the if statement

```
if direction == 1: 
    print("Joystick is turning right")
```